# PHP/MySQL not returning number of rows in database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm attempting to count the number of rows in my database for a pagination script. My entire script works until it comes down to counting the rows.

This is the code that should be counting my rows[$conn is a variable set with my database login - it is used throughout this code and works, except for this bit].

```
$limit = 2;
$rows = mysql_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT count(*) FROM pilotOperators"));
$total=ceil($rows/$limit);
```

To test my code I added this to the end of my page:

```
echo "Total:" . $total . "<br>";
echo "Rows:" . $rows . "<br>";
echo "Limit:" . $limit . "<br>";
```

And this is the result taken from my source code:

```
Total:0<br>Rows:<br>Limit:2<br>
```

I've tried several variations and such, but nothing is returning a number.

---

SOLVED: Thanks to two different answers(apparently I had two mistakes).

One of my lines was changed to:

```
$rows = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM pilotOperators"));
```

And it works like a charm now.

Thanks Mureinik, and EyasSH

Comment: You're mixing calls to `mysql_*()` with calls to `mysqli_*()`. The two APIs are different and can't be intermixed. You also shouldn't use `mysql_*()` for new code. It's deprecated and will be removed from PHP 7 later this year.

Comment: Selecting count(row_name) causes the query to return a single row with a field named count containing your desired value. This may differ from your expected behavior.

Answer (score 3):

This line is your problem:

```
$rows = mysql_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT count(*) FROM pilotOperators"));
```

You are asking for `_num_rows()` **of** a `COUNT` query. If oyu loo kat the result of

```
mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT count(*) FROM pilotOoperators");
```

You'll find out that you will get one row and one column:

```
|----------|
| count(*) |
|----------|
| 233      | etc
|----------|
```

What you want is:

```
$rows_result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT count(*) FROM pilotOoperators")->fetch_row();
$rows = $rows_result[0];
```

It is generally always better to use a `COUNT` aggregate query than `num_rows`. When is the right time to use `mysqli_num_rows`? Well, if you are actually using the query for something else, but need to know the number of rows in advance, then its best not to make two separate queries here.

Comment: This worked but as Mureinik said I also had an issue using mysqli and mysql together. Both of your solutions helped and got it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix `mysql` and `mysqli` functions. If you're performing the query with `mysqli_query`, you should use [`mysqli_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) to get the number of rows:

```
$limit = 2;
$rows = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT count(*) FROM pilotOperators"));
$total=ceil($rows/$limit);
```

Comment: Of course, you should learn the Object Oriented approach, unless you like typing more.

Comment: I changed my code to what you posted and for the most part it worked. I was about to post about the new issue but EyasSH noticed the problem.

Thanks to your post and his my code is now $rows = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM pilotOperators")); and it works. Thanks so much.